# Is it possible to clone a Variable Group between PROJECTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know you can clone Variable Groups, but this is limited within the Project.
Is it possible to clone it to a different Project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such a feature to clone variable groups between Projects in azure devops UI portal.

However, you can achieve this using [variable group rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

First, you need to call get variable group rest api to get the variables content.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

Then use add variable group rest api to add the a new variable group to another project with the variable content from the Get rest api.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

Please below powershell script example:

```
# Get the variable group in projectA
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectA}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$PAT = "Personal access token"

$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get -ContentType "application/json" 

# Call add variable group rest api to add variable group in ProjectB
$updateurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectB}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$body = $result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -ContentType "application/json" -Method post -Body $body
```

You can also use azure devops command line `az pipelines variable-group create`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest) for more information.

Comment: I tried this, variable group not copied from project A to project B with in the organization

Comment: Thanks for this. My situation was slightly different because I needed to clone a variable group not only to a different project, but to a different organization too. In that case I needed a second PAT to use with the POST request which had permission to create variable groups in the second org.

Comment: Be careful, if you are using secrets in your variable group, these will be empty strings in the copied version

Answer (score 0):

An approach - using `curl`, `jq` and `xargs` - that has worked for me:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -u 'username':'<PAT>' 'https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<url encoded source project-name>/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.1-preview.1' \
| jq -c '.value[] | del(.id, .createdBy, .modifiedBy, .createdOn, .modifiedOn)' \
| xargs -d'\n' -L1 -I'{}' \
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u 'username':'<PAT>' -d "{}" 'https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<url encoded target project-name>/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.1-preview.1'
```

- The first `curl` command gets all available variable groups from the source project
- `jq` removes the specified keys from each json object and outputs them line by line (`-c`)
- `xargs` splits the input by newline (`-d'\n'`) and passes each line (`-L1`) to the `curl` command, that creates a new variable group in the target project