# Accessing an Azure variable group from a different organization in a yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I got a variable group in organization A in the library of Project1. I got a yaml pipeline in organization B in the repo of Project2. Usually to access a group, you just define it in the `variables` section, but in case of different organizations, how can the pipeline access the variable group?

Comment: Try adding powshell task and  using Get Variable Groups.  For your reference: [Is it possible to clone a Variable Group between PROJECTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572088/is-it-possible-to-clone-a-variable-group-between-projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no such a built-in feature in Azure DevOps to share the variable groups across organizations. Currently we even cannot share variable groups across team projects within the same organization.

There's already similar features suggested before :

- [Library of Variable and Task groups shared between all projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/library-of-variable-and-task-groups-shared-between/365752)
- [Add Organization Variable Groups](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-organization-variable-groups/363433)

As a workaround, you can use the Azure Key Vault task to pull data from Azure Key Vault. You can have as many Vaults as you like and use in one or all projects. Alternately, create a new variable group in organization B and enable “**Link secrets from an Azure key vault as variables**”. See [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) for details.